# How to check if a table is empty and if so, to delete all rows in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a series of SQL insert statements in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008. My question is: How can I check to see if an existing table has any rows, and if so, delete all the rows then continue with my insert statements?

Bascially, I'm looking for a statement that would do this:

If "greek_organizations" has data
delete all rows

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why bother? Just delete all rows. If the table is empty it is barely any resources and if it isn't it is pointless to check. Just Delete the rows and move on.

Comment: you can use truncate greek_organizations, this would be faster as there is no transaction involved.

Comment: @radar that is not true. You don't know if the OP is using a transaction or not (which has zero bearing on performance here). There may also be foreign keys which prevent truncating.

Comment: But if the table is empty a delete takes no more resources than a count.

Comment: @radar You cannot use truncate if there are FK relationships

Comment: @Blam, you are right

Comment: @SeanLange, that is correct. will take back my comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EXISTS` to check:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table])
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM [table]
        ---Or for fast delete use:  TRUNCATE TABLE [table]
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'nothing in table'
    END
```

Comment: Why top 1? And TRUNCATE is NOT a fast delete. It is a very different statement.

Comment: @Sean Lange what would you use if not `TOP 1`?

Comment: IF EXISTS(Select *...). There is no benefit to using top 1. It just adds confusion.

Comment: truncate is less documented then delete so it looks faster

Comment: @SeanLange Truncate is different statement that also deletes rows and is faster.  Fast delete is a fair characterization.

Comment: Technically speaking it doesn't delete rows, it deallocates data pages. It is faster because it only has to log page deallocations instead of row deletes. That of course assume it doesn't have foreign keys. :)

Comment: how can I wrap this to check all tables in DB?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with previous posters. The resulting state of the table will always be empty.. So you should always Truncate the table... Obs, I would check to ensure the table exists before Truncating
But this is the real solution:

```
if OBJECT_ID(N'Test', N'U') is not null
    Truncate Table Test;
```

To answer your question:

```
if (select count(1) from Test) > 0
begin
    Truncate Table Test;
End
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If exists(select * from  [greek_organizations] )
begin
delete from [greek_organizations]
end
else
begin
insert...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM greek_organizations) > 0
BEGIN
DELETE FROM greek_organizations
END
```

Comment: that's going to be slow if the table has 5 million rows !

Answer (score 0):

Why to check whether the table has any records? You can just write a delete query which deletes all the records before your insert queries.

Answer (score 0):

A quicker way of checking row count would be something like .....

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
                  WHERE Object_Name(Object_Id) = 'TableName')
BEGIN
  -- DELETE FROM TableName
  -- OR
  -- TRUNCATE TABLE TableName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete greek_organizations;  
insert into greek_organizations (desc) values ('one'), ('two'), ('three');
```

or

```
delete greek_organizations;
insert into greek_organizations (desc) 
select desc 
from staging_table;
```